# wrong output C after successful attempts

Tags: c

So i'm trying to solve this codeforce problem https://codeforces.com/contest/431/problem/A
.Basically i input 4 integers(a[0]...a[3]) and an array of integers between 1 and 4 then i need to output the sum of the string values according to the 4 initial integers.(check the codeforce's exemples)
So my code did work on the 5 initial tests but i had a wrong output on the 6th test 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAxKv.png)

Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int test=1;
    long s,result=0;
    long a[3];
    int i,x;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        if (a[i]==0)
            test=0;
    }
    scanf("%d",&s);
    while (s!=0)
    {
        if (test==0)
            break;
        x=s%10;
        s=s/10;
        result=a[x-1]+result;
        }   
    printf("%d",result);    
    return 0;
}
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you step through the code line by line in a debugger? That is the best way to debug code. Or if you have done that (or any other debugging) what did you find?

Comment: `long a[3];` does not have 4 elements, only 3. And `a[x-1]` can index at `a[-1]` which is out of bounds.

Comment: Also, if you do basic debugging, such as examining or printing out variables such as `s` you should at least be able to spot some key issues. Such as "does `s` have the value I expect"?

Comment: @WeatherVane i thought when declaring an array 0 is considered as an element.i'll be more cautious next time thanks

Comment: @kaylum i'll give it a try next time thanks

Comment: That is true: `a[0]` is considered as an element. `long a[4]` has 4 elements, `a[0]` thru `a[3]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have several problems with your code. But the most severe problem for which you are getting wrong output because you are using "%d" format specifier for long values, but its "%ld" actually. Using %ld will solve the problem.

Leaving rest of the problems for you to find out. Happy coding!